# mongod.cfg file not present in my Mongo installation on Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, rest

I dont have a mongod.cfg file present in my Mongo installation on Windows and I need to enable REST to solve the below error:

"REST is not enabled.  use --rest to turn on.
check that port 28017 is secured for the network too."

The link below suggested having the following in the in the mongod.cfg.However I don't have such a file.How do I proceed?

```
logpath=C:NoSQLmongodblogmongo.log 
dbpath=C:NoSQLmongodbdata
rest=true
```

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/mongodb-using-the-web-based/

Answer (score 0):

Found it ! 
In order to host Mongo using http on localhost on Windows,run Mongod using CMD as below:
mongod --httpinterface --rest --bind_ip localhost

This opens port 28017 for http connection.In your browser now type: 
http://localhost:28017/

Now click on listDatabases to find the databasename .

And the URL to use in the node.js application to connect to this localhost database would be:

var URL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/'
where  would be the database just found in the step above.

Hope that helps someone else !!